# How to printf in bash with multiple arguments?

Tags: bash, printf

How do I print a formatted system date + hostname using printf in bash.

Something like `printf "%s:%s\n" date hostname`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
printf "%s:%s\n" "$(date)" "$(hostname)"
```

Comment: Or more succinctly, thus: `printf "$(date):$(hostname)\n"`

Comment: @devnull that was cute and simple.

Comment: Instead of invoking a subshell with date in it, why not simply rely on the date format of bash's _built-in_ implementation of `printf(1)`?
For example: `printf '%(%a %b %d %T %Z %Y)T:%s\n' -1 $(hostname)`

Comment: @Mikhail - jmcnama ~> printf '%a %b %d %T %Z %Y)T:%s\n' -1 $(hostname)
-0x1.0000000000000p+0 SNEDAP03 0bash: printf: `T': invalid format character
jmcnama@SNEDAP03 ~> bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.52(1)-release (sparc-sun-solaris2.10)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is why - that is a new feature.  Good point for modern bash, though +1

Comment: @devnull: that can be problematic. "`printf` interprets escape sequences and format specifiers in the format string. If variables are included, any escape sequences or format specifiers in the data will be interpreted too, when you most likely wanted to treat it as data.". From https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2059

Comment: @devnull aside from what was already pointed out, doesn't that defeat the purpose of printf? There's no (string) format whatsoever in your example.